# How to include androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1 in my android project

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I try to add `androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1` in my project and when I look the dependencies of `androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1` I found this :

```
\--- androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1
     +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0
     |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0
     |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0 -> 2.2.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0
     |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0
     |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    +--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |    |    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0
     |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0 -> 1.2.4
     |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0
     |    |    |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |    |    |         \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0
     |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:[2.1.0] -> 2.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0 -> 2.2.0
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0 (*)
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0 -> 2.2.0
     |    |    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    +--- androidx.activity:activity:1.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0
     |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.1 -> 2.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0 -> 2.2.0 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0 -> 2.2.0
     |    |    |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |    |    |         +--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0 (*)
     |    |    |         +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.2.0 (*)
     |    |    |         \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.2.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.2.0 (*)
     |    +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.1.0
     |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.1 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0
     |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |    |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0
     |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0 (*)
     |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 (*)
     +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.4 (*)
     +--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0
     |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |    \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
     |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |         +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |         +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0
     |         |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |         |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |         |    +--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0
     |         |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |         |    +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0 (*)
     |         |    +--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0
     |         |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |         |    \--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0
     |         |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |         +--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0 (*)
     |         +--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0 (*)
     |         +--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0
     |         |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |         |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |         |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0 (*)
     |         +--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0 (*)
     |         +--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0
     |         |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |         |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |         |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0 (*)
     |         +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0 (*)
     |         +--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0
     |         |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |         |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |         |    \--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0 (*)
     |         +--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0
     |         |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
     |         |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
     |         \--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0 (*)
     +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
     \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
```

So it's terrific to add all those aar/jar manually :(
How can I do ?

Comment: The answer is obvious: include any jars that androidx.preference:preference is dependent on. Just because there are quite a number of them does not mean there is an issue with doing so. It may also depend on exactly what you are using from the preference package as to which jars you need to add. You need to clarify your question with what the actual problem is

Comment: @DaveNottage I know but including all those aar is a huge job :( especially that many of them have also resouces not only jar. it's possible but it's will take me one week to do it :( You didn't do a tool to automate this by the way as I remenber ?

Comment: I started doing automation for this kind of thing, however I put it on hold. I _might_ start it again - I am interested in what classes you are using from androidx.preference

Comment: @DaveNottage it's because PreferenceManager is deprecated in android 29, and now we must use androidx.preference.PreferenceManager instead :(